# Android studio：Can't recognize the wav file as the second param to MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-studio, wav

When I use MediaPlayer to play a wav file:

[image]

I got a problem:Cannot resolve method 'create(com.edu.hitsz.aircraftwar.SecondFragment, int)'
I assume that this might because the wav type was wrongly recognized, so I change the associated type do like this answer:

> [Why does android studio not recognize .wav / .mp3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889497/why-does-android-studio-not-recognize-wav-mp3-files)

[image]

But my problem is still not solved. What's wrong?

Comment: are you shure that `raw` files aren't resolved properly? what is `this` on your code screenshot (NEVER post text as image)? should be `Context`, so use `requireContext()` method instead of `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter is a context, not a fragment.  Use getActivity() instead of this.